# How do I slope a retaining wall for a raised patio?

Tags: walls, patio, pavers

I am planning a raised paver patio for my back door. The patio will be 8' x 12' and will need to be 2' off the ground. My understanding is that a patio should have a 1/8" slope away from the house. How do I achieve this when laying my cinder block for the walls? I am thinking I should lay the block on a level footer and then slightly slope the wall away from the house. The length of the wall would be 8', so the end of the wall would be 1" lower than the start. That would be too much for mortar to fill in wouldn't it?

I'm guessing I am missing something obvious here. Do I even need a footer for this short of a wall? If not, could I just slope the ground using gravel as a base?

Thanks for any input you can provide! Just want to make sure I do this right.

Comment: You're going to be filling a block retaining wall with (roughly ) 192 cubic feet of dirt. According to [this page](https://www.dirtconnections.com/how-much-does-a-cubic-foot-of-dirt-weigh/) (no affiliation) that's a bit more than 7 tons of dirt. I'd suggest you want your retaining wall well connected to a footer since you want to do this right.

Comment: In fairness, it's not the weight of the earth that's important here so much as the height.  Still, I'm not sure cinder block is the right material here.

Answer (score 1):

You can build the 1/8" per foot slope into the footer. No need to complicate it with a level footer.

How much and how deep you need a footer depends mostly on what the frost depth in your area is, if any.